# How to install a Linux distro with encryption that does not have encryption support in the installer?

Tags: linux, system-installation, encryption, luks

I quite like the features of Blend os [[1](https://blendos.co/),[2](https://github.com/blend-os)] and would like to use it. Unfortunately, my main machine is a laptop and its lack of full disk encryption sounds like a non-starter. Is there any way to use the manual partitioning method (or other method) to install it with full disk encryption? I am not particularly familiar with how LUKS encryption works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline plan:

- Deploy a minimal installation in a throwaway partition at the end of the disk.
- Use that to partition the remainder of the disk and set up encryption.
- Copy the running minimal copy to the new encrypted partition(s).
- Remember to update `grub` to include the new installation. If you've encrypted root you will need an initramfs for the boot process.
- Boot from that new installation.
- Check everything works. Wipe the minimal installation and reuse the disk space.

I've done this with Debian installations and although it works it is fiddly and easy to miss a step. Make sure you have a suitable [Rescue CD](https://system-rescue.org/) on hand

Comment: Could you expant on what the second step entails? like a said I'm not that familiar with LUKS. a guide or docs would do great. or just a more in depth explanation.

Comment: You would do well to create a loopback filesystem and first become a [little more familiar](https://gist.github.com/dbehnke/ad19ca8f1ccf80aebca5) with LUKS in a safe/controlled environment